# Rebuild checks out and removes GlobalSection(Performance) from .sln file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, projects-and-solutions

When rebuilding the solution, the `.sln` file is checked out and following section is removed:

```
GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
    HasPerformanceSessions = true
EndGlobalSection
```

Why is it happening and how can I prevent checking out solution file on rebuild?

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and TFS 2015

Comment: Does the removes only occurs  in one  particular sln or all of the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the solution  will not check out the file in source control by default.

The delete action trigger the check out. Because version of the Solution file not sync each other from source control and local project folder.

So, the real problem is why rebuild the .sln file will remove the GlobalSection(Performance) file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the Visual Studio issue, refer to following links for details:

[Section in solution file causes continual merge conflicts in a team environment](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817315/section-in-solution-file-causes-continual-merge-conflicts-in-a-team-environment)

[Visual Studio Performance Explorer adds user-specific information to the .sln file, which causes issues for teams with multiple developers](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1951562)